# Apache Ant downgrade

Tags: apt, downgrade, apache-ant

I need Apache Ant 1.8 on my Ubuntu 14. But there is only one version available:

```
$ apt-cache madison ant
    ant | 1.9.3-2build1 | http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Where or how can I get an older version of Apache Ant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I haven't found any matching PPA I did it just manually:

```
$ cd ~
$ wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.8.4-bin.tar.gz
$ tar xvfvz apache-ant-1.8.4-bin.tar.gz
$ sudo mv apache-ant-1.8.4-bin /opt/ant
$ sudo sh -c 'echo ANT_HOME=/opt/ant >> /etc/environment'
$ sudo ln -s /opt/ant/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant
```